# How can we use more than 100 coordinates in google road map api (sna to road)

Tags: angular, google-maps, tracking

I need to integrate tracking to my angular project and am using google map, snap to road api and polyline for perfect drawing...but snap to road have limit of 100 coordinates..how can i increase the limit?

Am using firebase for real time database....

Comment: You need to make multiple requests to the API.

Comment: @geocodezip am just a beginner .... actually i have created an android app to fetch lat and long but am not getting the exact coordinates from android app...so i am  using snap to road and polyline to correct the road and  to draw..but from android app i will get n(numbers) of coordinates and i need to dynamically split them and  then first sent to snap to road and the return value to polyline..so there am stuck ..can u please help me ?

Comment: @geocodezip how can i call snap to road multiple time and send recent data from firebase to snap to road? also how can i send all these data to polyline ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot increase the limit of 100 GPS points per Roads API request. You'll need to make multiple calls to the API.

Example of 1 request to Roads API:

https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?path=-35.27801,149.12958|-35.28032,149.12907|-35.28099,149.12929|-35.28144,149.12984|-35.28194,149.13003|-35.28282,149.12956|-35.28302,149.12881|-35.28473,149.12836&interpolate=true&key=YOUR_API_KEY

I recommend you go through Google's guide which includes a demo with polylines https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap

Hope this helps!